# Working with git behind a dynamic DNS

Tags: git, ssh

I am have a git repository on a machine with a dynamic DNS address - its IP address changes once every few days.

Every git operation that involves communicating with the machine yields the following warning:

> reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo
>   for 1-2-3-4.isp.net
>   [1.2.3.4] failed - POSSIBLE
>   BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

I assume this is SSH warning about a possible MITM attack. Is there anyway to suppress said warnings?

Comment: im having this problem. on linux the simple answer is in /etc/ssh/ssh_config: `CheckHostIP no`. now to somehow turn on this setting in windows...

Comment: @Nacht [`CheckHostIP no` is now the default](https://serverfault.com/a/1109184/115583) in SSH, since the security added was pretty minimal if you're doing PubKey authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call this from within your network, or from outside? The former case simply doesnt work, because of some restrictions of the NAT-protocol. Just use the local adress, if you are "at home". You can add multiple remotes to your repository, so for `fetch`, `push` and so one you can choose which remote it should use.

For example

If you are at home

```
git remote add homenet 192.168.1.1:/foo/bar/repo.git
git push homenet master
```

If you are somewhere outside

```
git remote add outside mynet.dyn.example.com:/foo/bar/repo.git
git push outside master
```

Another solution would be, if you add your dynamic hostname into your hostsfile (should be `/etc/hosts` under linux, dont know, where it resides under windows), so your machine will not using the dns for resolving anymore.

```
192.168.1.1 mynet.dyn.example.com
```

Comment: Inside the LAN this is obviously not a problem. The issue is with WAN access. Obviously - this means using /etc/hosts is not possible in this case (since this is a dynamic IP we're talking about).