# can't push to github repo after replasing to another PC

Tags: git, github, ssh, xubuntu

I was starting my project and used github for remote repo.

I changed my OS from Ubuntu to Xubuntu.

But I copied all my old files to the new location.

I keep working with my program I need to push changes.

I generated new SSH key and added to github.

I tried to push changes but it prints strange info:

```
nazar@nazar-desctop:~/Documents/workspace/NewYearGift$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
nazar@nazar-desctop:~/Documents/workspace/NewYearGift$ sudo git push -u origin master
[sudo] password for nazar:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

***Update:***

I recreated this project again, and now it asks me about my passphrase:

```
nazar@nazar-desctop:~/Documents/workspace/NewYearGift$ git commit -m "correct smole issue"
[master e2cbdec] correct smole issue
 1 file changed, 29 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)
 rewrite README.md (89%)
nazar@nazar-desctop:~/Documents/workspace/NewYearGift$ git push
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/nazar/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 843 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:nazar-art/NewYearGift.git
   3fb0853..e2cbdec  master -> master
```

Now it works but why so strict?

Can smb explain?

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an SSH key you have the option to add a passphrase to it. This is not mandatory, but it does provide an added layer of security.

You are being prompted for a passphrase because your key has has one.

It is possible to remove the passphrase if you want, but I'd recommend using an *agent* instead. When using an agent, you can give your passphrase once and you won't be promoted to enter it again for a certain amount of time.

Depending on your operating system and desktop environment you have a number of options for running an agent. OpenSSH provides this method:

```
ssh-add -t 5h
```

This will prompt you for your passphrase immediately, and then let you work for five hours without having to re-enter your passphrase. See the [manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-add) for details.

The time formats understood by OpenSSH can be found in the [manpage for `sshd_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current#end).

Comment: `5h` means 5 hours or 5 days?

Comment: @nazar_art Yes, the manpage I linked to points to the manpage for `sshd_config`, which [lists time formats](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current#end). I will edit my answer to include this information.

Comment: better change to weeks

Comment: If you really want you can omit the `-t <duration>` altogether. The agent will stay active as long as you are logged in.

Answer (score 2):

> Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known

You need to fix your system's resolver. For some reason it cannot resolve the IP address for github.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ssh url isn't an [one using an scp syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309):

```
github.com:username/yourRepo
```

Because if it is, ssh will look for an `~/.ssh/config` file to resolve "`github.com`"

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
```

You can use the original ssh url:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/username/yourRepo.git
```

You could also try and switch to an https url

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/yourRepo
```